Where have people discussed "higher" arithmetic-geometric means?
The arithmetic-geometric mean of two nonnegative real numbers $x,y$ is obtained by taking their arithmetic and geometric mean
$$ a_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x + y), \quad g_1 = (xy)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
and then iterating this process:
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_n + g_n), \quad g_{n+1} = (a_n g_n)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
and taking the limit of either sequence:
$$ \text{agm}(x,y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n $$
There's no need to stop here.  For example, we can try to define the "arithmetic-arithmetic-geometric mean" of $x$ and $y$ in a similar way using the arithmetic mean and arithmetic-geometric mean.  We start with these:
$$ A_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x + y), \quad \text{agm}_1 = \text{agm}(x,y) $$
and then iterate:
$$ A_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(A_n + \text{agm}_n), \quad \text{agm}_{n+1} = \text{agm}(A_n, \text{agm}_n) $$
If these limits exist and are equal, as I conjecture they do:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \text{agm}_n$$
then we can define the arithmetic-arithmetic-geometric mean of $x$ and $y$ by
$$ \text{aagm}(x,y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \text{agm}_n $$
One can also try to define an "arithmetic-geometric-geometric mean", and so on: indeed, one can try to play this game endlessly.  I feel someone must have done this, so my question is:
Where can I read about these "higher" arithmetic-geometric means?

Do you have any insights on how to prove this conjecture that some combinations of arithmetics and geometrics will yield limits that are equal?

You might show that both $A_{n+1}$ and $\text{agm}{n+1}$ lie between $A_n$ and $\text{agm}n$, so $|A{n+1} - \text{agm}{n+1}| \le |A_n - \text{agm}n|$, so $\lim{n\to \infty} |A_n - \text{agm}n|$ must exist; then show this limit cannot be positive, so it must be zero; then show that since each interval with $A_n$ and $\text{agm}n$ as endpoints contains the next such interval, and their lengths go to zero, $\lim{n \to \infty} A_n$ and $\lim{n \to \infty} \text{agm}_n$ both exist and must be equal.  There are details to fill in here, of course.

Ah right, this makes sense.
